# Common DRY principle violation React Native/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I seem to be having a reoccurring issue that I'm hoping there is a design solution out there that I am not aware of.

I'm running into the situation where I need to dispatch the exact same things from two different components. Normally I would set this to a single function and call the function in both of the components. The problem being that if I put this function (that requires props.dispatch) in some other file, that file won't have access to props.dispatch.

ex.

```
class FeedScreen extends Component {
.
.
.
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let {appbase, navigation, auth, dispatch} = this.props

        //This is to refresh the app if it has been inactive for more
        // than the predefined amount of time
        if(nextProps.appbase.refreshState !== appbase.refreshState) {
            const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'Loading',
            });

            navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
        }
.
.
.
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    info: state.info,
    auth: state.auth,
    appbase: state.appbase
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FeedScreen)

class AboutScreen extends Component {
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const {appbase, navigation} = this.props

        //This is to refresh the app if it has been inactive for more
        // than the predefined amount of time
        if(nextProps.appbase.refreshState !== appbase.refreshState) {
            const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'Loading',
            });

            navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
        }
    }
} 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    info: state.info,
    auth: state.auth,
    appbase: state.appbase
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AboutScreen)
```

See the similar "const navigateAction" blocks of code? what is the best way to pull that logic out of the component and put it in one centralized place.

p.s. this is just one example of this kind of duplication, there are other situations that similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most natural way to remove duplication here (with a react pattern) is to use or Higher Order Component, or HOC. A HOC is a function which takes a react component as a parameter and returns a new react component, wrapping the original component with some additional logic.

For your case it would look something like:

```
const loadingAwareHOC = WrappedComponent => class extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    // your logic
  }

  render() {
    return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
}

const LoadingAwareAboutScreen = loadingAwareHOC(AboutScreen);
```

Full article explaining in much more detail:
https://medium.com/@bosung90/use-higher-order-component-in-react-native-df44e634e860

Your HOCs will become the connected components in this case, and pass down the props from the redux state into the wrapped component.

btw: componentWillReceiveProps is [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). The docs tell you how to remedy.

Comment: thank you I'm definitely going to try this out and thanks for the tip about componentWillReceiveProps being deprecated. I guess I could add conditionals to the WrapperComponent so as to do different things in the loadingAwareHOC component depending on what the wrapper component is. I do foresee a situation where I would need to consolidate functionality for the HOCs because I'm guessing I can only really use one at a time.

Comment: K after a bit of research it looks like I can use redux's compose to add a bunch of HOCs if I want, also think you need to use this.props in the above example, that got me stuck for a while.